# Xamarin Android can't view files

Tags: android, file, xamarin

I'm trying to download a database file from my application off of my Android device. I run C:\Users\Jared\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\monitor.bat which brings up the Android Device Monitor. The file I'm looking for should be in /data/data/myApp.myApp/files/mySQLiteDB.db3, but I can't seem to open the /data/ folder. How can I access the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically Android Device Monitor only displays your application when it has debugging enabled and the app is running. If you can't find the file within the file explorer, then using `adb pull` from a terminal would do the trick:

```
adb pull /data/data/myApp.myApp/files/mySQLiteDB.db3
```

The above command would download the file from the device into the directory the `adb pull` was executed from.

Comment: When I try that I get `failed to copy '/data/data/myApp.myApp/files/mySQLiteDB.db3' to './myApp.db3': Permission denied`. So I tried `adb shell` and then `su`. It seems it can't find `su` or it is hidden somewhere else because I get `/system/bin/sh: su: not found`. I tried `root` also and it's the same problem. I'm using a Motorola XT907.

Comment: Was the apk built in release or debug mode?

Comment: Yeah it was in debug mode. I figured it out. I just changed the permissions on the file in my code like so: `using (StreamWriter dbFile = new StreamWriter(OpenFileOutput("mySQLiteDB.db3", FileCreationMode.WorldReadable | FileCreationMode.WorldWriteable)))
            {
                dbFile.Close();
            }`. After that `abd pull` worked just fine.